# undefined reference to `WinMain@16 in vs code through code runner

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

whenever I try to run c++ code in vs code using the code runner (using the run button ) it shows this error .
If I try to run the same by selecting all the code and then run it through it get compile

Comment: Please give us a minimal example. Otherwise, we cannot figure out what you problem is.